# string search via regex ? any better way?

Tags: php, regex

I want to search a text file in php for a special condition: When first time string matched, start collecting texts and when second time same string matched, stop collecting texts.

eg. If string is 'world' and searching it on below line:
'our world has a 196 countries, but only 192 of them are UN's member. our world is extra-ordinary.'

Then I want this text:'has a 196 countries, but only 192 of them are UN's member. our' in matched variable.

I have tried many regex in preg_match() but no result so is there any better way to do it ?

thanks

Comment: If you show us your regexp we can try to help

Comment: as answer given by joseph I tried that regex but no result

Comment: @Bhavin: what do you mean by 'no result'? - Joseph included a demonstration of it working.

Comment: @halfer I have commented about that in joseph's answer.

Comment: If there are other texts for which the required regex should work, you should definitely add them to your question. Downvoted, to encourage adding greater detail on your next question.

Comment: @halfer I added that example to explain my situation only, it is not my actual text. my actual text is too long to post here

Comment: How large is your text?  And how are you reading it in?  line by line, or all at once?  Are you looking to get all the "world -- world" sets?  Cause it sounds like http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php might be a better choice.

Comment: Sorry, that's deprecated.  Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = file($filename);
$keep = false;
$keepTrailing = true; //Flag that decides wether to keep trailing capture segments or not.
$extractions = array();
$current = '';
foreach($lines as $line){
    $parts = preg_split('/\bworld\b/i', $line);
    $current .= $parts[0];
    for ($i = 1; $i<count($parts); $i++){
        if ($keep) $extractions[] = $current;
        $keep = !$keep;
        $current = $parts[$i];
    }
}
if ($keep && $keepTrailing)
    $extractions[] = $current;
var_dump($extractions);
```

[Here it is in action.](http://ideone.com/0kqGRg)

Basically, by iterating through the file once, you can simply split each line on the key word ("world") - I used the `\b` anchor to ensure that it didn't split on "worldly" or other junk.  I've included a flag to decide whether to keep trailing capture segments.  You don't need that, necessarily, but it might help.  The only unintuitive portion of this solution is keeping the current capture in a `$current` variable, which basically allows you to keep scanning across multiple line breaks.

You know, this could easily be made into a function.

```
function capturingSearchWithKeyword($filename, $keyword, $keepTrailing = true, $trim = false){
    $lines = file($filename);
    $keep = false;
    $extractions = array();
    $current = '';
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $parts = preg_split("/\\b$keyword\\b/i", $line);
        $current .= $parts[0];
        for ($i = 1; $i<count($parts); $i++){
            if ($keep){
                if ($trim) $current = trim($current);
                $extractions[] = $current;
            }
            $keep = !$keep;
            $current = $parts[$i];
        }
    }
    if ($keep && $keepTrailing)
        $extractions[] = $current;
    return $extractions
}
```

[Check it out...](http://ideone.com/WfYX4w)

Comment: thats the answer I am looking for. I will modify it to my needs, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```
/(?<=world ).*?(?= world)/
```

See it here in action: http://regex101.com/r/tW2bT8

---

...and here's a demo using PHP: http://codepad.viper-7.com/DucTKE

Comment: yes I tried that and it will work in this example but not in my texts coz . my actual text contains much more than that. ie many -,.? and all that. I want to get that text between particular string as it is.

Comment: btw thanks for that regex101 link, now I can try many regex there

Comment: My actual text is too long to post here

Comment: I might try `/(?<=\bworld )((?! world\b).)*/s`  it crosses newlines, and captures trailing capture segments.